# Add unique XML Element values to a select list

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to add unique XML Child Element values to a select list. Here is what I have so far

XML:

```
<Student>
  <record>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
  </record>
  <record>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
  </record>
  <record>
    <Name>John</Name>
  </record>
  <record>
    <Name>John</Name>
  </record>
  <record>
    <Name>John</Name>
  </record>
  <record>
    <Name>Jill</Name>
  </record>
  <record>
    <Name>Jill</Name>
  </record>
  <record>
    <Name>James</Name>
  </record>
</Student>
```

XSLT:

```
  <xsl:key name="NameKey" match="Name" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="Student">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>
          <select>
              <xsl:for-each select="record">
                <option>
                <xsl:element name="Name">
                  <xsl:value-of select="Name[generate-id() = generate-id(key('NameKey',.)[1])]" />
                </xsl:element>
                </option>
              </xsl:for-each>            
          </select>
        </td>
       </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/record" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am successfully getting unique values in the list, but the list also displays empty string for the non unique values in the list. So my list has the following values:

```
Jack

John


Jill

James
```

Is there any way to getting rid of those empty string values in the list?

Comment: Please show us an example of the XML input, so we can reproduce the problem. -- P.S. I don't see that you are collecting **attribute** values; the word *attribute* has a very precise meaning in XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated my question. Sorry for the miss-type, I meant element values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to getting rid of those empty string values in the list?

Yes, just move the predicate with the key lookup to the `xsl:for-each`. With your current code, *all* those nodes are handed to the `xsl:for-each`, including the duplicates.

By the way, this line

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/record" />
```

Does not do anything, because the outermost element node is not called `record`. What was your intent here?

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="NameKey" match="Name" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="Student">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>
          <select>
              <xsl:for-each select="record/Name[generate-id() = generate-id(key('NameKey',.)[1])]">
                <option>
                <xsl:element name="Name">
                  <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:element>
                </option>
              </xsl:for-each>            
          </select>
        </td>
       </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/record" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option>
               <Name>Jack</Name>
            </option>
            <option>
               <Name>John</Name>
            </option>
            <option>
               <Name>Jill</Name>
            </option>
            <option>
               <Name>James</Name>
            </option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Rendered HTML**

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! I removed "<xsl:apply-templates select="/record" />" line as well

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that this can be achieved by using `[not(.=preceding::*)]` as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Student">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <xsl:for-each select="record/Name[not(.=preceding::*)]">
                            <option>
                                <xsl:element name="Name">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </xsl:element>
                            </option>
                        </xsl:for-each>            
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/record" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I personally think that is's more clear this way that you are only processing each Name element once.

Comment: This is not a good method - see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html